# git clone x as "y" - (renaming repo locally)

Tags: git, git-clone

Here are the docs for git clone

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Normally we clone a repo like so

```
git clone x
```

however, I want to rename the repository locally, so it would be something akin to

```
git clone x as y
```

looking at the docs, it's not clear if this is possible or kosher, does anyone know how to do this?

it looks like this works:

```
git clone x y
```

according to the docs:

```
<repository>

    The (possibly remote) repository to clone from. See the URLS section below for more information on specifying repositories.
<directory>

    The name of a new directory to clone into. The "humanish" part of the source repository is used if no directory is explicitly given (repo for /path/to/repo.git and foo for host.xz:foo/.git). Cloning into an existing directory is only allowed if the directory is empty.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is, it's the very last parameter (directory) in the documentation.

`git clone your.reporitory yourownname`

Other than that, there is nothing you need to do. A git-repository does not have a *name* other than the directory it resides in.

Answer (score 0):

That would be renaming the repo folder. That is, after cloning you will do:

```
mv x y
```